# I want to append the files to $_FILES on multiple times input type files image select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am making a portal. I have an attribute of input type multiple. It works flawlessly if a user uploads multiple images in 1 time. The real issue comes if user closes the box and he want to add an extra image. Lets say he add 10 photos the first time and he closes the box. Then he clicks again and uploads the last image. In this case his first 10 images are lost from $_FILES. Can any1 suggest a solution that I can work on?

Comment: Just a question ? But how will you know that if user wants to add new image or he wants to select again. ?

Comment: I can set a flag for that.

Comment: can you pleas share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to do this, will be using ajax request every time when file input change.
for example you can do something like this, using form data(or without it):

```
$("#myInput").change(function() {
   var formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('formData', file);
   $.ajax({
       url: 'file.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       success: function(){
         // 
      }
   });
});
```

this is just example, you should edit this code to fit your case